# Who gets turned into a tree in "Tortall and Other Lands"?

Tags: tamora-pierce, tortall-universe

In the book Tortall and Other Lands, there is a story about a tree who becomes a man because Numair turns a man into an apple tree, and there has to be balance.

Do any of Tamora Pierce's other books mention who Numair turns into a tree? It seems like a pretty major thing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The mage's name was [Tristan Staghorn](http://tamorapierce.wikia.com/wiki/Tristan_Staghorn) (in Pierce's novel *[Wolf-Speaker](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wolf-Speaker)*).